# Como melhorar código

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Possuo o seguinte método:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AlterarRequerimentoAsync(RequerimentoViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var projeto = await this.ProjetoApplicationService.ObterProjetoAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                var plantio = await this.PlantioApplicationService.ObterPlantioPeloIdProjetoAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                if (plantio.Count == 0)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("PlantioNaoInformado", Mensagens.PlantioNaoInformado);
                    return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
                }
                var talhao = await this.TalhaoApplicationService.ListarTalhaoPorIdProjetoAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                if (talhao.Count == 0)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("TalhaoNaoInformado", Mensagens.TalhaoNaoInformado);
                    return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
                }
                var detentor = await this.DetentorApplicationService.ListarDetentoresPorIdProjetoAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                if (detentor.Count == 0)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("DetentorNaoInformado", Mensagens.DetentorNaoInformado);
                    return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
                }
                var imovelRural = await this.ImovelRuralApplicationService.ObterImovelRuralPeloIdProjetoAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                if (imovelRural == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ImovelRuralNaoInformado", Mensagens.ImovelRuralNaoInformado);
                    return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
                }
                var inventario = await this.InventarioApplicationService.ObterInventarioPorIdProjetoAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                if (inventario == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("InventarioNaoInformado", Mensagens.InventarioNaoInformado);
                    return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
                }
                var prioridade = await this.PrioridadeApplicationService.ObterPrioridadePorIdProjetoAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                if (prioridade == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("PrioridadeNaoInformada", Mensagens.PrioridadeNaoInformada);
                    return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
                }
                var processamentoGeo = await this.ProcessamentoGeoApplicationService.ObterProcessamentoGeoPorProjetoIdAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                if (processamentoGeo == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ProcessamentoGeoNaoInformado", Mensagens.ProcessamentoGeoNaoInformado);
                    return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
                }
                var procurador = await this.ProcuradorApplicationService.ListarProcuradoresPorIdProjetoAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                if (procurador.Count == 0)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ProcuradorNaoInformado", Mensagens.ProcuradorNaoInformado);
                    return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
                }
                var representanteLegal = await this.RepresentanteLegalApplicationService.ObterRepresentanteLegalPorIdProjetoAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                if (representanteLegal == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("RepresentanteLegalNaoInformado", Mensagens.RepresentanteLegalNaoInformado);
                    return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
                }
                var responsavelTecnico = await this.ResponsavelTecnicoApplicationService.ListarResponsaveisTecnicosPorIdProjetoAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                if (responsavelTecnico.Count == 0)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ResponsavelTecnicoNaoInformado", Mensagens.ResponsavelTecnicoNaoInformado);
                    return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
                }
                var taxaDar = await this.TaxaDarApplicationService.ObterTaxaDarPorIdProjetoAsync(model.IdProjeto);
                if (taxaDar == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("TaxaDarNaoInformada", Mensagens.TaxaDaroNaoInformada);
                    return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
                }
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[] { };
                if (model.Arquivos.First().TempId.HasValue)
                {
                    var metadata = await this.FileServer.ReadFileAsync(model.Arquivos.First().TempId.Value);
                    if (metadata != null)
                    {
                        fileBytes = await this.FileServer.ReadFileContentAsync(model.Arquivos.First().TempId.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var file = await this.ArquivoApplicationService.ObterArquivoPorIdAsync(Convert.ToInt32(model.Arquivos.First().Id));
                        fileBytes = file.Conteudo;
                    }
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Arquivos.First().Id))
                {
                    var file = await this.ArquivoApplicationService.ObterArquivoPorIdAsync(Convert.ToInt32(model.Arquivos.First().Id));
                    fileBytes = file.Conteudo;
                }

                ArquivoData arquivo = model.Arquivos?.Select(x => new ArquivoData
                {
                    Conteudo = fileBytes,
                    Nome = x.FileName,
                    TipoConteudo = x.ContentType
                }).First();

                await this.RequerimentoApplicationService.IncluirAlterarRequerimentoAsync(arquivo, model.IdProjeto);

                this.SuccessMessage = "O Projeto de número: "
                    + projeto.NumeroProjeto
                    + " foi finalizado com sucesso.";
                return Json(new { redirect = Url.Action("Index", "Projeto", new { Area = "Projeto" }) });
            }
            return PartialView("_Alterar", model);
        }
```

Como posso melhorá-lo a parte de validação, como podem ver coloquei varios `return PartialView("_Alterar", model);` que é para quando entrar no if retornar a msg de erro e permanecer na tela atual.

Obs: O ModelState está valido, portanto entrará no if IsValid...

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de usar varios `return`, você poderia envolver a função em um `try-catch` e então fazer um `throw` com alguma mensagem de erro talvez para terminar o processamento. A vantagem disto é que se futuramente desejar este comportamento de como interrompe o processo, você iria fazer isto em um só lugar, no `catch` ao invés de ter que modificar todos esses `return`.

Aconselho também a tentar a tentar separar a tarefa em múltiplas partes para ficar mais organizado e legível. Poderia fazer inicialmente as verificações de "NãoInformado" em um método separado, depois outro método que retorna o valor de `fileBytes`.